# jQuery click event on radio button doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code to trigger a click event on some radio buttons! but it doesn't get fired! can any one help me with this!

**CODE :**

```
$("#inline_content input[name='type']").click(function(){
    if($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val() == "walk_in"){
        $('#select-table > .roomNumber').attr('enabled',false);
    }
});
```

**RADIO BUTTONS**

```
<form class="type">
<input type="radio" name="type" checked="checked" value="guest">In House</input>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="walk_in">Walk In</input>
</form>.
```

**Update**

Tried `onChange()` too but not working.

Comment: `OnChange` isn't a thing, it's `change`. Also, why not use `focus`?

Comment: The event handler gets fired for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6UZKN/, even with the `if` statement: http://jsfiddle.net/6UZKN/1/.

Comment: use `removeAttr('enabled')` to be sure. Not all browsers support `enabled="false"`.

Comment: @Broxzier: Good point. The problem seems not to be the handler, but the use of `.attr`. `.removeAttr` would work, but `.prop` would work fine as well.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It fires. Check demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/kbAk3/

```
$("#inline_content input[name='type']").click(function(){
    alert('You clicked radio!');
    if($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val() == "walk_in"){
        alert($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val());
        //$('#select-table > .roomNumber').attr('enabled',false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Correct `</input>`, your code `html` in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 18):

There are a couple of things wrong in this code:

1. You're using `<input>` the wrong way. You should use a `<label>` if you want to make the text behind it clickable.
2. It's setting the `enabled` attribute, which does not exist. Use `disabled` instead.
3. If it would be an attribute, it's value should not be `false`, use `disabled="disabled"` or simply `disabled` without a value.
4. If checking for someone clicking on a form event that will CHANGE it's value (like check-boxes and radio-buttons), use `.change()` instead.

I'm not sure what your code is supposed to do. My guess is that you want to disable the input field with class `roomNumber` once someone selects "Walk in" (and possibly re-enable when deselected). If so, try this code:

HTML:

```
<form class="type">
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="type" checked="checked" id="guest" value="guest" />
        <label for="guest">In House</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="walk_in" value="walk_in" />
        <label for="walk_in">Walk in</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="roomnumber" class="roomNumber" value="12345" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("form input:radio").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "walk_in") {
        // Disable your roomnumber element here
        $('.roomNumber').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        // Re-enable here I guess
        $('.roomNumber').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k28xd/1/

Answer (score 5):

Personally, for me, the best solution for a similar issue was:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="selectAll" value="true" />
<input type="radio" name="selectAll" value="false" />
```

**JQuery**

```
var $selectAll = $( "input:radio[name=selectAll]" );
    $selectAll.on( "change", function() {
         console.log( "selectAll: " + $(this).val() );
         // or
         alert( "selectAll: " + $(this).val() );
    });
```

*The event "click" can work in place of "change" as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Best answer so far

Answer (score 1):

A different way

```
$("#inline_content input[name='type']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "walk_in" && $(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#select-table > .roomNumber').attr('enabled', false);
    }
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cB6xV/

Comment: You could simplify the body of the event handler to `$('#select-table > .roomNumber').prop('enabled', this.value !== 'walk_in');`. And better use `.prop` for boolean attributes.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're `#inline_content` isn't there! Remove the jQuery-Selector or check the parent elements, maybe you have a typo or forgot to add the id.

(made you a jsfiddle, works after adding a parent `<div id="inline_content">`: http://jsfiddle.net/J5HdN/)

Answer (score 0):

put ur js code under the form html or use $(document).ready(function(){}) and try this.

```
$('#inline_content input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                if($(this).val() == "walk_in"){
                    alert('ok');
                }
});
```